# Check if any word in the list present in string python

Tags: python

I have nearly 50k documents in a mongo collection somewhat like this:

```
{"title":"sample title sample title",
 "content":"test content test content",
 "reply":{
           "replyContent":"sample reply content test"
          }
}
```

and I have an array of words something like this:

```
wordArr = ["sample","test"]
```

I need to match if any word form wordArr present in my collection of document. I have to iterate over each document from the collection and have to search if any of the word given in array id present in either of the fields i.e title , content and replyContent

Comment: wordArr can be switched to a set for O(1) lookup -- but you still have to iterate over the documents and extract the fields.

Comment: @JohnColeman: well i have to make a report sort of which would be one time task its jus i need to fetch data from db and store the result in the excel , the only place i am getting stuck is how to do the search think keeping in mind that the search result has to ignore case

Comment: how deep can the nesting be and are there other values other than strings?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work assuming your mongo collection is in a dictionary (sorry I have no experience with mongo collections.

```
dict = {"title":"sample title sample title",
        "content":"test content test content",
        "reply":{"replyContent":"sample reply content test"}
       }

wordArr = ["sample","test"]

for word in wordArr:

    for key, value in dict.iteritems():

        if word in value:
            print 'Word: `%s` present in `%s`: %s' % (word, key, value)

        if key=='reply':
            for key2,value2 in value.iteritems():
                print 'Word `%s` present in `%s`: %s' % (word, key2, value2)
```

This will give you the following output:

```
> python test.py
Word `sample` present in `replyContent`: sample reply content test
Word: `sample` present in `title`: sample title sample title
Word: `test` present in `content`: test content test content
Word `test` present in `replyContent`: sample reply content test
```

Comment: can we use if ( any ) for search

Comment: This would return True for `"sample" in "resample ..."`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return True or False:

```
d = {"title": "sample title sample title",
     "content": "test content test content",
     "reply": {
         "replyContent": "sample reply content test"
     }
     }

word_set = {"sample", "test"}
def is_present(d, st):
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for val in d.values():
                if any(word in st for s in val for word in s.split()):
                    return True
        else:
            if any(word in word_set for word in v.split()):
                return True
    return False

print(is_present(d,word_set))
```

If you have arbitrary levels of nesting you might need a nested approach